# facebook login failure on iOS device

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cocoonjs

I am making an HTML5 app using cocoonjs, when trying to login into facebook as i click the login button it opens the facebook app or facebook website on safari, after this if i close the facebook app/safari then my app doesnt get notified of this kind of login failure

how do I detect this?

this is my code

`if (this.socialService && !this.socialService.isLoggedIn()) {
     this.socialService.login(function(session) {
         self.log(session);
         if (session.status !== "connected") {
             console.log("not connected");
         }
     }, { scope: "publicprofile,user_friends" });
} else {
    console.log("not connected");
}`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3#dialogresponse) for the Facebook js sdk has an example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  } else {
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
  }
});
```

Check the `session.status` of your code to check the conditions as shown in the example. If status is anything other than `connected` or `not_authorized` it could mean that the Facebook app/safari was closed.

Comment: dont know why but i am not getting any callback at all